# problem in react-chatbot-kit as actions is not transfering the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was using react-chatbot-kit in which I am facing an error on click of button (got it). It was done with help of action provider, which technically is using redux to transfer the function to perform the action. But when I was clicking on the got it button, it ends up giving error 'initialAction not defined'.

```
 import React from 'react';
 
 const ActionProvider = ({ createChatBotMessage, setState, children }) => {
 
     const initialAction = () => {
         const message = createChatBotMessage('Just type in your name to begin.');
         
         setState((prev) => ({
             ...prev,
             messages: [...prev.messages, message]
         }))
     }
 
     const updateState = (message, checker) => {
         setState((prev) => ({
             ...prev,
             messages: [...prev.messages, message],
             checker,
          }))
     }
 
 
     return (
         <div>
             {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
                 return React.cloneElement(child, {
                     actions: {
                         initialAction,
                     },
                 });
             })}
         </div>
     );
 };
 
 
 export default ActionProvider;
```

and gotitbtn.js

```
 import React from "react";
 import "./gotitbtn.css";
 
 export default function Gotitbtn(props) {
     const initialAction = () => {
         props.actions.initialAction()
      };
 
      
     return (
         <div className="gt_btn_main">
             <button className="gt_btn_button" onClick={() => initialAction()}>
                 Got it!
             </button>
         </div>
     );
 }
```

and config.js for loading the button widget

```
 // Config starter code

 import { createChatBotMessage } from "react-chatbot-kit";
 import "./config.css";
 import BotAvatar from "./BotAvatar";
 import Gotitbtn from "./Gotitbtn";
 
 
 const config = {
     initialMessages: [
         createChatBotMessage(`Hello, Welcome to student info system!`, {
             widget: "gotitbtn",
         }),
     ],
     botName: "HappilyEver",
     
     customStyles: {
         botMessageBox: {
             backgroundColor: "#e8e7e7",
         },
 
         userMessageBox: {
             backgroundColor: "#i1i1i1",
         },
 
         chatButton: {
             backgroundColor: "#5ccc9d",
         },
     },
 
     customComponents: {
         botAvatar: (props) => <BotAvatar />,
     },
     
 
     widgets: [
         {
             widgetName: "gotitbtn",
             widgetFunc: (props) => <Gotitbtn {...props} />,
         },
     ],
 };
 
 export default config;
```

I was trying to make a chatbot but it is giving me an error. Please help me. Error is: `initialAction is not a defined function`

exact error is `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialAction') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialAction') at initialAction (http://localhost:3000/main.7ae6d4e6e2d0bf5a823e.hot-update.js:27:26) at onClick (http://localhost:3000/main.7ae6d4e6e2d0bf5a823e.hot-update.js:33:22) at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12200:18) at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12244:20) at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12301:35) at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12315:29) at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16459:7) at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16485:11) at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16496:9) at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16505`

Answer (score 1):

this is happening since you are passing empty object in the actions props of the message parser.

The code below can be found in `MessageParser.jsx`

```
{React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      parse: parse,
      actions: {},//empty
    });
  })}
```

Change it into

```
{React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      parse: parse,
      actions,
    });
  })}
```

Now you can run your code again. I hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code in gotitbtn.js

```
 const initialAction = () => {
     props.actions.initialAction()
  };
```

to this

```
const initialAction = () => {
         props.actionProvider.initialAction()
      };
```

Comment: it still dosent work exact error is